# Create HTML form from XML

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have a number of different xml files that I need to edit from an html form. I want the form to be generated dynamically (the files could any valid xml structure) and I want to save the modified xml content back to the database in the same structure.

I've seen a few examples of using XSLT when you know the structure of the xml, but in this case I don't.

So, two real points:

1. How do I dynamically create an html form from an unknown xml structure
2. How do I save the modified content back to the same xml structure

Comment: If it's true that "the files could any valid xml structure" and you have no idea what tags you will encounter, the problem is unsolvable.  You have to know SOMETHING about the input and what you want the output HTML to look like.  You should start by editing your post to include everything you DO know about the input (some samples would be helpful) and what you want to produce.

Comment: This is not an XSLT question. There is no transformation involved. You have a web page form with a string source (populated by AJAX or whatever means) that after edition you sumit to a web service (to store in database or whatever you want)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I JUST ran across this site the other day, maybe it's what you're looking for...

http://www.datamech.com/XMLForm/

Good Luck!

Comment: That looks like exactly the kind of thing I'm after, is it available as a library?

Comment: @Scobal: Sorry, but I really don't know anything about it. I just happened to stubble across it the other day.