# Generating HTML forms from JSON or XML feed using JQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, json

I would like to  create an HTML form based on XML  or JSON data using Jquery and I also plan to validate any form fields that may be empty or incorrect.

I would like to know if there are any other programs/functions that generate such a form dynamically on the fly and the best way to go about implementing this. Any jquery widgets or libraries that work best with workings examples would be much appreciated

And also what feed to best use in this scenario XML or JSON and explain why?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've found some of these that might help you:

**Generating forms from JSON schema:**

- [how to create a html form using a JSON definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508871/how-to-create-a-html-form-using-a-json-definition)
- http://neyric.github.com/inputex/examples/json-schema.html
- [JavaScript to generate/render dynamic HTML form from JSON or similar data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042086/javascript-to-generate-render-dynamic-html-form-from-json-or-similar-data)
- [Any tool to generate html form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376618/any-tool-to-generate-html-form)

**Generating forms from an XML schema:**

- http://www.totallysmartit.com/examples/xml/questionnaire/
- [Create HTML form from XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736658/create-html-form-from-xml)
- http://www.datamech.com/XMLForm/

**Samples from different libraries to generate form:**

- http://www.alpacajs.org/examples.html
- http://jsonforms.io/#/examples
- http://schemaform.io/examples/bootstrap-example.html

Answer (score 10):

Just to give you another choice, a library I created:

https://github.com/brutusin/json-forms

> JSON Schema to HTML form generator, supporting dynamic subschemas (on the fly resolution). Extensible and customizable library with zero dependencies. Bootstrap add-ons provided

```js
 var bf = brutusin["json-forms"].create({
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "s1": {
      "type": "string",
      "title": "A string",
      "description": "A string input"
    },
    "num1": {
      "type": "integer",
      "title": "A number",
      "minimum": 1,
      "maximum": 10,
      "multipleOf": 3,
      "description": "An integer multiple of `3`, between `1` and `10` (inclusive)"
    },
    "array1": {
      "type": "array",
      "title": "An array values",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "value": {
            "type": "string",
            "title": "Value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
var container = document.getElementById('container');
bf.render(container);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/brutusin.json-forms/1.3.2/css/brutusin-json-forms.min.css'/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css'/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/brutusin.json-forms/1.3.2/js/brutusin-json-forms.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/brutusin.json-forms/1.3.2/js/brutusin-json-forms-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
<hr>
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="alert(JSON.stringify(bf.getData(), null, 4))">getData()</button>&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="if (bf.validate()) {alert('Validation succeeded')}">validate()</button>
```

More live examples at http://brutusin.org/json-forms