# How to enable and disable textbox based on option button More then one field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found the below code to *enable and disable* textbox based on the option button but i want to more than *20 fields* like that.

I want to write lot of scripts for that, is there easy way to create 20 fields like that

Please any one help me regarding this

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $(function() {
    window.invalidate_input = function() {
      if ($('input[name=opt13]:checked').val() == "Yes")
        $('#others').removeAttr('disabled');
      else
        $('#others').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    };

    $("input[name=opt13]").change(invalidate_input);

    invalidate_input();
  });
}); //]]>
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<label>Did you study any school</label>&nbsp&nbsp
<input type='radio' name='opt13' value='Yes' id="" />Yes
<input type='radio' name='opt13' value='No' id="" />Others</td>
<br />
<br />
<label>Enter MatexBranch:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="textbox" name="others" id="others" />
```

Comment: First this is not a good approach. `window.load` has `$(function(){})`. Why...

Comment: `for` or `foreach` or `$.each` or any one of a number of ways to iterate over variables would work if you parametrise your variables. If this is a fairly long/complex form with validation and conditional formatting, perhaps have a look at this [question about generating forms based off JSON or XML](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12905849/648350)

Comment: @haxxxton Its better to use more generic code and using `this` to find element to be manipulated.

Comment: @Rajesh, my misunderstanding about what OP meant by "fields _LIKE_ this", rather than identical except for `name`.. I assumed they wanted a more robust form building solution that something so specific to the html structure provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to make code reusable, remove any specific code like `$("#...")`. Instead, navigate to element using `this`. For this, you can use `.siblings` function of jquery.

Also there is not need for `if...else`. You can set value as `true` or `false` to enable/ disable element.

Also, instead of binding `change` on radio using `name`, do it using a combination of selector as `name` will be different for every group.

```js
$(function() {
  var invalidate_input = function() {
    $(this).siblings('.input-value').attr('disabled', $(this).val() !== "Yes");
  };

  $(".section input[type='radio']").on("change", invalidate_input);
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>

<div class="section">
  <label>Did you study any school</label>&nbsp&nbsp
  <input type='radio' name='opt13' value='Yes' id="" />Yes
  <input type='radio' name='opt13' value='No' id="" />Others</td>
  <br />
  <br />
  <label>Enter MatexBranch:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="textbox" name="others" class="input-value" />
</div>

<div class="section">
  <label>Did you study any school</label>&nbsp&nbsp
  <input type='radio' name='opt14' value='Yes' id="" />Yes
  <input type='radio' name='opt14' value='No' id="" />Others</td>
  <br />
  <br />
  <label>Enter MatexBranch:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="textbox" name="others" class="input-value" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could like this, creating a jQuery object of each radio/checkbox element. And adding a data attribute (in this case data-target) where you fill in an id or classname for the target input field. In this case you don't need to have them as siblings.

```
var toggleInput = {
    init: function() {
         var $toggles = $('.js-toggle-input');

         $toggles.each(function(index, elem) {
              var $elem = $(elem);

              $elem.on('change', function(e) {
                   var currentTarget = $(e.currentTarget);
                   var targetInputField = currentTarget.data('target');

                   if ( currentTarget.is(':checked') && currentTarget.val() == "Yes") {
                       $(targetInputField).remoeAttr('disabled');
                   } else {
                       $(targetInputField).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                   }
              });
         });
    }
}

$(function() {
    toggleInput.init();
});
```

```html
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<label>Did you study any school </label> &nbsp&nbsp
<input type='radio' name='opt13' value='Yes' id="" class="js-toggle-input" data-target="#others"/>Yes
<input type='radio' name='opt13' value='No' id="" class="js-toggle-input" data-target="#others"/>Others</td>
<br /><br />
<label>Enter MatexBranch: </label> &nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="textbox" name="others" id="others" />
```

Working here:
https://jsfiddle.net/djr9g0dc/2/