# Convert XML string to HTML form in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml

I need to build a HTML form from an XML string using Javascript/jQuery.

I came through the below answer

[XML to Form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3787328/5475205)

The answer talks about this - [XML to Form generator](http://www.datamech.com/XMLForm/formGenerator5.html)

That's exactly what i want, but i could not find the javascript code in the provided link.
I have tried parsing the XML string and iterating through nodes to build the Form, but there are lots of bugs in my code and i am short of time.
Below is the code i tried:

```
function xmlToForm(text) {
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");

    var htmlForm = '<form action="">';


    var rootNode = xmlDoc.childNodes[0];

    htmlForm += nodeToHtmlForm(rootNode);
    htmlForm += '</form>';

    function nodeToHtmlForm (node) {
        var form = '';

        if(node.childNodes.length > 0) {
            node.childNodes.forEach(function(childNode) {

            if(childNode.childNodes.length > 0) {

                if(childNode.firstChild.nodeValue) {
                    form += '<div class="form-group">'
                    form += '<label><h4>'+ childNode.nodeName +'</h4>'+ '</label>';
                    form += '<input class="" id="id" value=' + childNode.firstChild.nodeValue + '>';
                    form += '</div>'
                } else {

                }

                form += '<br><h4>'+ childNode.nodeName +'</h4><br>'

                childNode.childNodes.forEach(function(grandChildNode) {
                    console.log(grandChildNode);
                    form += nodeToHtmlForm(grandChildNode)
                });
            }

            else {
                form += '<div class="form-group">'
                form += '<label>'+node.nodeName+'</label>';
                form += '<input class="" id="id" value='+node.firstChild.nodeValue+'>';
                form += '</div>'
            }

            });
        }   else {
                if(node.firstChild) {
                    form += '<div class="form-group">'
                    form += '<label>'+node.nodeName+'</label>';
                    form += '<input class="" id="id" value='+node.firstChild.nodeValue+'>';
                    form += '</div>'
                } else {
                    form += '<br><h4>'+ node.nodeName +'</h4><br>';
                }
            }

        return form;
    }
    return htmlForm;
    //document.getElementById("htmlForm").innerHTML = htmlForm;
}
```

Someone please help me build the HTML form from XML.

Comment: I dont think you can do that efficiently in js. The site you mentioned doesn't use js either. After googling a bit I found that there are ways using XSLT to achieve what you want. I think you should parse the xml in the server side and return the html back to the user like an api.

Comment: @orangespark, actually this is a chrome extension where i have to fetch the XML from background page, convert it to HTML form and display in the extension. I am restricted to use only javascript/jQuery for this.

Comment: why dont u just use the get or ajax call to get the data i think you can do that using js and jquery

Comment: Still i will have to write the processing logic in server side code which will be called by ajax. I dont have any server here, i am restricted to only Javascript.

Comment: but heavy computation like this are preferred to be done in the server itself as u have to parse the xml and compile it to html. Anyway try using js as u dont have server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those curious or couldn't find the solution anywhere else

```
function xmlToForm(xmlDoc) {
        var framed_html = "";

        xml_to_html($(xmlDoc[0].children[0]));      

        function xml_to_html(xmlDoc) {
            if (xmlDoc[0].firstElementChild) {
                framed_html += "<fieldset class='back-fieldset'><legend>" + xmlDoc[0].nodeName + "</legend>";
                xml_to_html($(xmlDoc[0].firstElementChild));
                framed_html += "</fieldset>";
                if (xmlDoc[0].nextElementSibling) {
                    xml_to_html($(xmlDoc[0].nextElementSibling));
                }

            } else {
                framed_html += "<div class='form-group'><label>" + xmlDoc[0].nodeName + "</label>";
                framed_html += "<input type='text' value='"+xmlDoc[0].innerHTML+"'></div>";

                if (xmlDoc[0].nextElementSibling) {
                    xml_to_html($(xmlDoc[0].nextElementSibling));
                } else {
                    framed_html += "<hr>";
                }
            }

        }

        return framed_html;
    }
```

Comment: Hello Vishal, Can you share the HTML form as well. Have you called the function onclick button ? Have you pasted xml file content or uploaded it . or gave the link of the content

Answer (score 0):

This will definitely help you. But you can't do it efficiently with jquery alone.

https://github.com/davidmoten/xsd-forms

Comment: How can this help the OP? Please explain. Its about xsd i.e xml schema document conversion to html

Comment: @orangespark I hope you have concrete knowledge of what xml and xsd specifies. Actually the xsd is xml itself. Its purpose is to validate the structure of another xml document. The xsd is not mandatory for any xml, but it assures that the xml could be used for some particular purposes. The xml is only containing data in suitable format and structure.

Comment: u just googled the difference when i asked u :P 
u could have just shown the link instead of copy pasting it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2334009/2791802... LOL

Comment: i get that you want to make some reputation but that doesn't mean you have to just answer things u don't have any idea about or in your words "concrete knowledge of the subject".  Be patient and Prosper. :)

Comment: OMG. Why are you feeling so offended. LOL, Thanks for the reserch @orangespark but the current link was https://questionfocus.com/what-is-the-difference-between-xml-and-xsd.html which gives the complete implementation. I have read through it and just tried to share the knowledge. Keep calm!!

Comment: okay buddy if thats what you think i am not gonna burst ur bubble :D

Comment: Tysm for your kind thought :)